# How to populate combobox with ArrayList from another Form?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I want users to create their accounts, which will be stored in an arraylist in the Sign up form, while the Log in form has a combobox with all the usernames so the user can select their username, type their password and proceed.

I get an error on `cmb_user1.Items.Add(username);` where username does not exist in the current context.

Class:

```
public class User
    {
        public string fname;
        public string lname;
        public string username;
        public string password;

        public string Fname
        {
            get { return fname; }
            set { fname = value; }
        }

        public string Lname
        {
            get { return lname; }
            set {lname = value; }
        }

        public string Username
        {
            get { return username; }
            set { username = value; }
        }

        public string Password
        {
            get { return password; }
            set { password = value; }
        }

        public User() { }

        public User (string fname, string lname, string username, string password)
        {
            this.fname = fname;
            this.lname = lname;
            this.username = username;
            this.password = password;
        }

    }
```

Sign up form:

```
 public partial class sign_up_form : Form
    {
        ArrayList allUsers = new ArrayList();

        public sign_up_form()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btn_create_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                if (txt_password.Text == txt_confirm_password.Text)
                {
                    allUsers.Add(new User(txt_fname.Text, txt_lname.Text, txt_username.Text, txt_password.Text));
                    log_in_form login= new log_in_form(this, allUsers);
                    login.Show();
                    this.Hide();
                }
            }
            catch 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong!");
            }
        }
    }
```

Log in form:

```
public partial class log_in_form : Form
    {
        sign_up_form formParent;
        ArrayList allUsers;
        public log_in_form(sign_up_form par, ArrayList _allUsers)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.formParent = par;
            this.allUsers = _allUsers;

            cmb_user1.DataSource = allUsers;
            cmb_user1.Items.Add(username);
        }

        private void btn_signup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sign_up_form signup = new sign_up_form();
            signup.Show();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. There is no username in that context so this is expected behaviour. What happens when you comment out that line? What problem do you have then? What is you goal with this line?

Comment: In login form, there is no username object exists.So, you need to create an object from user class and get the username object

Comment: My goal is to only get the username showing in cmb_user1 so that's the purpose of the line. The arraylist holds fname, lname, username and password.

Comment: @MertAkkanat Im new could you please further explain that with an example code?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you needed `username`? Username already exists in your arraylist but if you really need it, try this:

```
if (txt_password.Text == txt_confirm_password.Text)
{
    allUsers.Add(new User(txt_fname.Text, txt_lname.Text, 
    txt_username.Text, txt_password.Text));
    log_in_form login= new log_in_form(this, allUsers,createdUser);
    login.Show();
    this.Hide();
}

public log_in_form(sign_up_form par, ArrayList _allUsers,Users newUser)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.formParent = par;
    this.allUsers = _allUsers;

    cmb_user1.DataSource = allUsers;
    cmb_user1.Items.Add(newUser);
}
```

Or if you need usernames which are in arraylist try:

```
foreach(var item in allUsers)
{
    cmb_user1.Items.Add(item.username);
}
```

Comment: ```log_in_form login= new log_in_form(this, allUsers,createdUser);``` is giving an error under ```createdUser``` the name does not exist in the current index.

Comment: also the ```foreach``` function gives the same error under ```username```